# Error Android Plugin with id 'jetty' not found

Tags: android, gradle

Mi pregunta es esta.

Acabo de crear un proyecto y no me deja sincronizar el Gradle, me pone todo el rato que no encuentra el plugin jetty , he probado a bajar de versión al gradle, cambiar el classpath, ...pero haciendo esto me dice que hay una versión más reciente y que tengo que actualizar.

¿Qué tendría que hacer para que me funcione?

Este es el código de html:

```
apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "jetty"

gwt {
    gwtVersion='2.8.0' // Should match the gwt version used for building the gwt backend
    maxHeapSize="1G" // Default 256m is not enough for gwt compiler. GWT is HUNGRY
    minHeapSize="1G"

    src = files(file("src/")) // Needs to be in front of "modules" below.
    modules 'com.mygdx.game.GdxDefinition'
    devModules 'com.mygdx.game.GdxDefinitionSuperdev'
    project.webAppDirName = 'webapp'

    compiler {
        strict = true;
        disableCastChecking = true;
    }
}

task draftRun(type: JettyRunWar) {
    dependsOn draftWar
    dependsOn.remove('war')
    webApp=draftWar.archivePath
    daemon=true
}

task superDev(type: de.richsource.gradle.plugins.gwt.GwtSuperDev) {
    dependsOn draftRun
    doFirst {
        gwt.modules = gwt.devModules
    }
}

task dist(dependsOn: [clean, compileGwt]) {
    doLast {
        file("build/dist").mkdirs()
        copy {
            from "build/gwt/out"
            into "build/dist"
        }
        copy {
            from "webapp"
            into "build/dist"
            }
        copy {
            from "war"
            into "build/dist"
        }
    }
}

draftWar {
   from "war"
}

task addSource {
    doLast {
        sourceSets.main.compileClasspath += files(project(':core').sourceSets.main.allJava.srcDirs)
    }
}

tasks.compileGwt.dependsOn(addSource)
tasks.draftCompileGwt.dependsOn(addSource)

sourceCompatibility = 1.6
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]


eclipse.project {
    name = appName + "-html"
}

Y este es el de test:
buildscript {


    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'de.richsource.gradle.plugins:gwt-gradle-plugin:0.6'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:2.3.1'


    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "my-gdx-game"
        gdxVersion = '1.9.8'
        roboVMVersion = '2.3.1'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
        aiVersion = '1.8.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"

    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"

    }
}

project(":ios") {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "robovm"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-rt:$roboVMVersion"
        compile "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:$roboVMVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"

    }
}

project(":html") {
    apply plugin: "gwt"
    apply plugin: "war"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion:sources"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion:sources"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"

    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"

    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

Si podéis ayudarme sería de mucha ayuda, muchas gracias

Comment: El plugin `jetty` es obsoleto, [será retirado a partir de Gradle 4.0](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jetty_plugin.html). Según he visto ya estaba dando problemas desde Gradle 3.0. Deberás [cambiar la configuración `jetty` por `Gretty`](http://akhikhl.github.io/gretty-doc/Getting-started.html), como recomienda Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Con Gradle 3.0 no funciona correctamente `jetty` y en `Gradle 4.0` si es que tu proyecto lo requiere, definitivamente no funcionará ya que se marco como obsoleto y en esta versión existe un modulo que se eliminara.

> Este plugin se eliminó a partir de Gradle 4.0. Recomendamos usar el plugin [Gretty](http://akhikhl.github.io/gretty-doc/Getting-started.html) en su lugar.

(Aunque en realidad me parece que es en la versión 4.1 de Gradle)

---

**Configuración para el uso de [Gretty](http://akhikhl.github.io/gretty-doc/Getting-started.html):**

> Agregue lo siguiente a "build.gradle" de su aplicación web:

```
apply plugin: 'war' apply from:
 'https://raw.github.com/akhikhl/gretty/master/pluginScripts/gretty.plugin'
```

> o inserta en tu "build.gradle":

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    // enable this to use snapshot versions of Gretty:
    // maven { url 'http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local' }
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'org.akhikhl.gretty:gretty:+'
  }
}

repositories {
  jcenter()
  // enable this to use snapshot versions of Gretty:
  // maven { url 'http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local' }
}

apply plugin: 'org.akhikhl.gretty'
```

Comment: Preffered option is to avoid akhikhl version. Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50119925/error-while-replacing-jetty-plugin-to-gretty-plugin-gradle